# Opening Android Security Settings from a website

Tags: android, android-intent, hyperlink, html

Is it possible to open the Android Security Settings from a website, e.g. using an `<a href=?>` tag?

Supposedly, [it is possible to launch Android Intents from Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents), but there seem to be some requirements for the intent receiver. For example,  activities must have the category filter [android.intent.category.BROWSABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_BROWSABLE), which I am not sure that the security settings implement.

I tried:

```
<a href='intent://#Intent;action=android.settings.SECURITY_SETTINGS;end;'>
Open Android Security Settings</a>
```

and

```
<a href='intent:#Intent;action=android.settings.SECURITY_SETTINGS;end;'>
Open Android Security Settings</a>
```

Neither one works. The first one (with the double slashes) gives me a page not found error and the second one simply does nothing.

Did I miss something in the link or are there entirely different ways to achieve this? I'm looking for solutions that work on as many different versions of Android and browsers as possible.

Comment: This feels like if not a 'security hole', most likely a 'bad idea' to let arbitrary websites invoke the security settings on a consumer device. I would be interested to know what 'benefit' could come from this capability.

Comment: @MorrisonChang It would just be a convenience feature for the user, since you need to go to the Security Settings to allow Apps from Unknown Sources if you want to install a downloaded APK. Would be nice if, right next to the download link for the APK, there was a link that takes you to these settings. Clearly, simply clicking the link would not be able to make any changes to the settings, just saves you a whole bunch of clicks to get there...

Comment: What a user has to do to enable side loading has been around since the beginning of Android. Amazon even gives instructions. https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201482620 Even 'convenience' features means that users become acclimated to possibly risky behavior and 'Untrusted Sources' would count. I'm afraid if you want that you'll have to give instructions in a similar fashion.